# Iterating through list of values in a dictionary c#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, logic

I have a dictionary defined as below ,

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionaryValues = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Since I have a List of values I want iterate through them and find out what values have ="true" in them 
Here is the source code what I have tried thus far

Would appreciate any help on this

```
List<string> listValues = new List<string>();

listValues.Add("value=true");

listValues.Add("value=false");

dictionaryValues.Add("Name", listValues);

            foreach (var item in dictionaryValues)
            {
                foreach (var item in item.Value)
                {
                    if (item.Contains("true"))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: the above code does not works?

Comment: the code looks good. apartment from `var item in item.Value` (here the item should be different name) what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: What's the issue? What is not working? Are you getting an exception? The results are wrong? What's the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Values property on the dictionary. Also, you'll have to rename one of the "item" variables in either of the foreach loops.

See also msdn [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netframework-4.8).

```
foreach (List<string> items in dictionaryValues.Values)
{
  foreach (string item in items)
  {
     if (item.Contains("true"))
     {
     }
  }
}
```

I've also made it explicit what types the "items" and "item" are for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

By using Linq you can do this with SelectMany and Where:

```
 var valuesWithTrue =  dictionaryValues.Values.SelectMany(x => x).Where(x => x.Contains("true"));
```